# ActionController::UrlGenerationError - missing required keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and am trying to build my first MVC app. I am trying to create a link file path and get this error message -

**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Pages#my_profile**
*No route matches {:action=>"show", :car_id=>10, :controller=>"bookings"}, missing required keys: [:id]*

This is the code I am using in the view

<% current_user.bookings.each do |booking| %>

```
  <%= link_to booking.car.make, car_booking_path(booking[:id])%></h2>
```

<% end  %>

When I type booking into the rails console I have access to the following hash

#<Booking id: 10, start_date: "2020-08-18", end_date: "2020-08-19", status: nil, user_id: 5, car_id: 5, created_at: "2020-08-18 17:34:41", updated_at: "2020-08-18 17:34:41">

so am unsure as to why, when booking[:id] is passed it is not picked.

my route is

**car_booking GET    /cars/:car_id/bookings/:id(.:format)       bookings#show**

Does anyone have any idea on what I am missing?
any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Notice your route is asking for two variables: :car_id and :id. The path in your view is only supplying the :id for the booking.  The path should be `car_booking_path(booking[:car_id], booking[:id])`.

Comment: @dbugger `[booking.car, booking]` instead of `car_booking_path(booking[:car_id], booking[:id])` saves you 26 taps of the keyboard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<% current_user.bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= link_to booking.car.make, [booking.car, booking] %></h2>
<% end %>
```

See, you have a nested route:

```
car_booking GET /cars/:car_id/bookings/:id(.:format) bookings#show
```

Which expects both `car_id` and `id`. You're only passing in one value, `booking[:id]`, which is in the first position, so it is interpreted as `car_id` (although it's actually `booking.id`). There is no second value in your arguments, so you get the `missing required keys: [:id]` message.

Note that if you used [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting), something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 

  ...

  resources :cars do 
    resources :bookings, shallow: true
  end

  ...

end
```

then you would just do:

```
<% current_user.bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= link_to booking.car.make, booking_path(booking)%></h2>
<% end %>
```

Also note that you can typically do `booking_path(booking)` instead of `booking_path(booking.id)`. In fact, as stated in the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you can use the pithier:

```
<% current_user.bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= link_to booking.car.make, booking %></h2>
<% end %>
```

If you don't want to use shallow nesting, you can do:

```
<% current_user.bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <%= link_to booking.car.make, [booking.car, booking] %></h2>
<% end %>
```

...and, as discussed [in the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) Rails will infer the `car_booking_path` helper.

In your question, you say you have access to the following hash:

```
#<Booking id: 10, start_date: "2020-08-18", end_date: "2020-08-19", status: nil, user_id: 5, car_id: 5, created_at: "2020-08-18 17:34:41", updated_at: "2020-08-18 17:34:41">
```

FYI, that's not a hash. That's an instance of the `Booking` class which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. To get the `id` from that instance, do `booking.id`, not `booking[:id]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, car_booking_path(booking.car, booking) worked. It's really obvious now you have pointed it out and makes total sense. Really appreciate you taking the time to take a look

Comment: Try `link_to booking.car.make, [booking.car, booking]` for an even shorter form. Also, please upvote/accept to help future searchers.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You've got an n+1 query going on there because you do `current_user.bookings` and then for each `booking` you do `booking.car`. You'll probably want to eager load the cars to avoid the n+1.

Answer (score 0):

As per the output from the routes, you need to pass two arguments id and car_id.
Try the below:

```
<%= link_to booking.car.make, car_booking_path(car_id: booking.car_id, id: booking.id)%></h2>
```

Comment: Replacing `car_booking_path(car_id: booking.car_id, id: booking.id)` with `[booking.car, booking]` saves 34 taps of the keyboard.

Comment: Just thought of saving a query to car since it will trigger a query to car with  *booking.car*

Comment: Good thought. I suspect `booking.car` will be a cached request since `booking.car` is already called with `booking.car.make`. But, the OP ends up with an N+1, which is a good point.

Comment: I think it will still trigger a cache query to car unless eager loaded.

Comment: Good point. The really important bit is that `booking.car.make` minimally causes an N+1 and merits eager loading. Thanks!